# Wrong Print Order With Web Request

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

I am trying to read data from Google Sheet API and get the last 5 rows. Here is my function:

```
func fetchData() {
    let range = "TestSheet"
    var convertedLogList : [Log] = []
    var fetchResult: [[String]] = []

    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: Globals.shared.YOUR_SHEET_ID, range: range)
    
    Globals.shared.sheetService.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let values = (result as? GTLRSheets_ValueRange)?.values else {
            print("No data found.")
            return
        }
        
        fetchResult = values.map { $0.map { $0 as? String ?? "" } }
        
        for row in fetchResult {
            // convert [String] to a Log object
            var log = Log()
            log.timestamp = row[0]
            log.nthTime = row[1]
            log.openNew = row[2]
            if row.count == 4 {
                log.note = row[3]
            }
            convertedLogList.append(log)
        }
        print("===== convertedLogList: ", convertedLogList)
    }
    
    var latestLogs : [Log] = []
    var counter = 0
    // take the latest 5 logs
    for log in convertedLogList.reversed() {
        if counter < convertedLogList.count && counter < 5 {
            counter += 1
            latestLogs.append(log)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    print("+++++ latestLogs: ", latestLogs)
}
```

I have 2 print statements in my code but the print order is wrong. Here is the print output:

> +++++ latestLogs:  []
> ===== convertedLogList:  [Log(id: xxxxxxxxx, timestamp: "10/24/2022", nthTime: "1", openNew: "Yes", note: "), Log(id:xxxxxxx,....) .... ]

I wonder why the print order is wrong. How can I utilize the `await` with Google Sheet API in Swift to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems you have almost figured this out already, you are making an asynchronous call so the print at the end is executed directly after the call has been made but before the response has arrived and the code in the closure gets executed.

Comment: Why not simply move the code you currently have at the end of the function to be inside and at the end of the completion handler?

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks, my friend! My code worked after putting the end of the function inside the completion handler. I also wonder if I can use the new ```await``` feature without using the completion handler?

Comment: If the API provides an `async` version of the method then sure, you can use `await`.

Comment: … and if doesn’t, you can write your own, wrapping it in [`withCheckedThrowingContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:)). See https://wwdcbysundell.com/2021/wrapping-completion-handlers-into-async-apis/.

Comment: The comments from HangarRash and the document from Rob are really helpful. Thank you all!